# Reading binary file byte by byte

Tags: java, io, binaryfiles

I've been doing research on a java problem I have with no success.  I've read a whole bunch of similar questions here on StackOverflow but the solutions just doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'm trying to read a binary file byte by byte.

I've used:

```
while ((data = inputStream.read()) != -1)
```

loops...

```
for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
```

loops...

But I only get empty or blank output.  The actual content of the file I'm trying to read is as follows:

> ¬í sr assignment6.PetI¿Z8kyQŸ I ageD weightL namet Ljava/lang/String;xp   > @4      t andysq ~     @bÀ     t simbasq ~     @I      t     wolletjiesq ~
>   @$      t rakker

I'm merely trying to read it byte for byte and feed it to a character array with the following line:

```
char[] charArray = Character.toChars(byteValue);
```

Bytevalue here represents an int of the byte it's reading.

What is going wrong where?

Comment: please provide expected result and actual result

Comment: actual result is 57 blank spaces...expected result is integer values

Comment: I think that it is problem with symbol displaying

Comment: Try to write bytes without converting to char

Answer (score 3):

Since java 7 it is not needed to read byte by byte, there are two utility function in [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/temp/test.txt");

// Load as binary:
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
String asText = new String(bytes, StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1);

// Load as text, with some Charset:
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

As you want to read binary data, one would use `readAllBytes`.

String and char is for *text*. As opposed to many other programming languages, this means Unicode, so all scripts of the world may be combined. `char` is 16 bit as opposed to the 8 bit `byte`.

For pure ASCII, the 7 bit subset of Unicode / UTF-8, byte and char values are identical.

Then you might have done the following (low-quality code):

```
int fileLength = (int) path.size();
char[] chars = new char[fileLength];
int i = 0;
int data;
while ((data = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    chars[i] = (char) data; // data actually being a byte
    ++i;
}
inputStream.close();

String text = new String(chars);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

The problem you had, probably concerned the unwieldy fixed size array in java, and that a `char[]` still is not a `String`.

For binary usage, as you seem to be reading serialized data, you might like to dump the file:

```
int i = 0;
int data;
while ((data = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
    char ch = 32 <= data && data < 127 ? (char) data : ' ';
    System.out.println("[%06d] %02x %c%n", i, data, ch);
    ++i;
}
```

Dumping file position, hex value and char value.

Comment: You mean data position, hex value and char value, right?

Comment: Yes %d = number, %x = hexadecimal number, %c char.

Answer (score 1):

it is simple example:

```
   public class CopyBytes {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new FileInputStream("xanadu.txt");
            out = new FileOutputStream("outagain.txt");
            int c;

            while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to read text(characters) - use Readers, if you want to read bytes - use Streams

Comment: I've used this example, and mention the while loop in my post. Still getting blank output.

Comment: Do you understand that outagain.txt is output ?

Comment: Yes I do...I amended the code to just print output and not write to file

Comment: Try to read another file. Maybe your file contain service symbol at the begining

Comment: Also maybe this symbols are not visible for you. try to count how many loop iterations are executes

Comment: When I try to read another file I get an error invalid stream header, it was a zip file.  It loops 57 times, which I don't know is correct...doubt it though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59569/discussion-between-alwynmalan-and-nagibator777).

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Apache Commons:

```
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
```

Then you can convert it to char:

```
String str = new String(bytes); 
Char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
```

Or like you did:

```
char[] charArray = Character.toChars(bytes);
```

To deserialize objects:

```
List<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your_file.dat");
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

try {
    while (true) {
        results.add(ois.readObject());
    }
} catch (OptionalDataException e) {
    if (!e.eof) throw e;
} finally {
    ois.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but getting blank output.

Comment: @alwynmalan Are you sure you are providing the correct path to the file, and the file is not empty?

Comment: Yes I throw and exception if file is not found.  It's a .dat file, is that perhaps the problem?  The contents are as in my original post.  Contains serialized objects

Comment: Do you want to deserealize object ?

Comment: If I want to read the file byte by byte, should it be deserialized?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: 
Use file.length() for they array size, and make a byte array. Then inputstream.read(b).
Edit again: if you want characters, use inputstreamreader(fileinputstream(file),charset), it even comes with charset.